# How do I return an entire matrix after having changed a certain value in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, methods, output

I have a very specific question about my example.

My goal is to change a certain value in a matrix and then return the entire matrix.

My code so far:

```
replace :: [a] -> (Int,a) -> [a]
replace [] _ = []
replace (_:xs) (0,a) = a:xs
replace (x:xs) (n,a) =
                      if n < 0
                      then (x:xs)
                      else x: replace xs (n-1,a)



setEntry :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
setEntry x i j aij = replace (x!!(i-1)) ((j-1),aij)
```

My goal is to get to the point where:

*setEntry [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,2,1]] 2 2 9*

results in

*[[1,2,3],[3,9,1],[1,2,1]]*

My current code only outputs the line, in which the value was changed.
So in this case:

*[3,9,1]*

I know, I would have to change the output type to [[Int]] in order to receive the entire matrix, for now I have it on the list type though, because this is what the method does.

I dont understand, how I can return the entire matrix, especially since I would have to copy it, no?

I am very grateful for any kind of help.

Thank you already in advance!

Comment: Hint: you need to call `replace` twice, one for the row, and one for the column.

Comment: Thank you! I spent the last 15 minutes trying this out but I appear to be brain dead or something. I haven't figured out on how to call replace on the entire matrix. Would you mind, giving me another hint on that?  :)

Comment: You're currently producing a result which _is_ the `i-1`th row.  So, what if you replace the whole `i-1`th row of the original matrix with the result you just produced?  Remember, when `a ~ [x]`, then the type of your `replace` function becomes `[[x]] -> (Int, [x]) -> [[x]]` and it works perfectly as a "row replacement" function for matrices.

Answer (score 1):

If you generalize your `replace` function to take an update function instead of a fixed value, you can use it both for the outer and for the inner list:

```
update :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
update _ _ []     = []
update 0 f (x:xs) = (f x) : xs
update n f (x:xs) = if n < 0
                     then (x:xs)
                     else x : update (n-1) f xs
```

Because if you want to map over the outer list, you cannot simply replace an inner list by a fixed value, but the new value depends on the old value. Just one element of the inner list changes.

Comment: (Aesthetic note: I would swap the first two parameters so that it chains cleanly without reversing the order of the indices...)

Comment: @luqui Thanks for your remark. But I do not understand, could you please elaborate a tiny bit?

Comment: Just that `update 2 (update 3 (const 42))` to update row 2 column 3 reads a bit easier than `update (update (const 42) 3) 2`.  Also related to the "end-weight" principle: the arguments that are likely to be (syntactically) more complex should be later in the argument list, to keep more arguments near the function they are applied to.  Haskell argument order is such an art though.

Comment: @luqui Yes, this reads much better. Thanks very much for the explanation. Nice, that your were able to spot this instantly.